# DNS issues with VirtualBox VM and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: virtualbox, 18.04

I have a new Ubuntu 18.04 VM running in VirtualBox on Windows 10.  I'm connected to a local network and able to resolve local addresses from Windows.  However, my Ubuntu VM can only reach internet addresses.

From the command line, I see my DNS server listed as 127.0.0.53 yet NetworkManager correctly displays the 10.x.x.x address of the DNS server on my local network.

I've fiddled around a bit with various network settings but I'm not sure how to resolve this.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT1:
Interestingly, my DNS servers appear to be correct but my browser and shell commands like nslookup aren't using it by default. When I run nslookup  , it works perfectly fine.

EDIT2: I tried the --natdnshostresolver1 command which @Fabby recommended, no luck there.

EDIT3: this is what my resolv.conf file looks like:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by 
resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Comment: What does `VBoxManage modifyvm szVMName --natdnshostresolver1 on` do where `szVMName` is tour Virtual Machine name?

Comment: No difference, I've tried that too.

Comment: How about $ systemctl status systemd-resolved.      resolved is the 18.04 name resolver

Comment: @StephenBoston that command show this: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 10.0.2.3

Comment: Which isn't the correct DNS server.

Comment: Your /etc/resolv.conf header is not standard for systemd-resolved. It mentions resolvconf. Have you installed resolvconf? That is not standard for 18.04 but you can make it work that way. See LDJames answer. If you have not installed resolvconf, take a look at the manpage for systemd-resolved, in particular the section on resolv.conf. It talks about support for a static resolv.conf which is an easy way through this.

Comment: Also: have you installed bind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve this by installing the **resolvconf** app from the repository.  Up until Ubuntu 18.04 LTS the app was installed by default.

```
$ sudo install resolvconf
```

After installing **resolvconf** on your VM client, add your desired DNS server to the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` file.

Place `nameserver [your preferred dns server]` at the bottom of the file.  After rebooting your VM client, you will see the content of the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` file in your `/etc/resolv.conf` file, which will take precedence of other settings.

Comment: L.D James, that worked. . . I'd love to know what was wrong but either way, it's working now.  Thanks!

Comment: @L. D. James That solved the issue I was having.   Do you know why some things were seeing the correct nameserver and some things weren't?  What exactly is this solution doing?

Comment: Hmm, right at the top of ```head``` it says ```DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND..```. So is there a more proper way to configure dns?

Comment: Did  you mean `sudo apt-get install resolvconf` ?